# Lebesgue Integrable pointwise convergent counter example

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $f, (f_n)$ are Lebesgue integrable, and if $(f_n)$ increasing pointwise to $f$, does it follow that $\int f_n \rightarrow \int f$

Am I correct?
$f_n(x)=\chi_{[0,1)}\cdot x^n$ is a counter example

Comment: Isn't that covered by the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lebesgue.27s_monotone_convergence_theorem)? (I am rather skeptical about the "increasing-ness" of the sequence you suggest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The statement is correct and thus there is no counter example.** The fact that $f_n$, $n\in\mathbb N$, **and** $f$ are integrable is much stronger than the setting in traditional monotone convergence theorem. Thus, we don't need non-negativity.

For each $n\in\mathbb N$, by monotonicity, we have
$$ f_1 \le f_n \le f $$
and thus
$$ f - f_1 \ge f - f_n \ge 0. $$
Since $f$ and $f_1$ are both integrable, it follows $f-f_1$ is integrable and dominates $f-f_n$. 
Thus, $f - f_n$ converges to $0$ in $L^1$.
That is, $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^1$.